# Passing data from template to python code in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building a web app using Django framework. How do I accept data selection from the user on a drop down in a template(HTML) and pass the data selected to my main python logic code(util.py) ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, provide the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you looking for [DTL or Jinja2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/) language?

Answer (score 1):

Django is a web framework. A web page can't pass data to a utility function directly. The only way the browser can communicate with the server is via a web request to a URL that is handled by a view. That view can then call any functions in your utils module, and return the result back to the user in the HTTP response.